# Datamatrix code generation with python

Tags: python, qr-code

I need to "encode" a string into a [Datamatrix code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) image, and am struggling the whole day to find a way (library) to do it.

Does anyone know a good python library for Datamatrix code generation? Or a way to do it?"

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Elaphe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elaphe/) library for barcode generation has datamatrix support.

Also, there is [pylibdmtx](https://pypi.org/project/pylibdmtx/)

Comment: `pylibdmtx` is still being updated actively and is now written in pure Python.

Answer (score 2):

There is a library **treepoem** that allows conversion to most of the barcode types, which is being updated frequently.

https://pypi.org/project/treepoem/

eg: UPC-A,EAN-13,ISBN,PZN,I. 2 of 5,Code 39,Code 93,Code 128,Datamatrix,PDF417,QR,Micro QR, Aztec.

```
import treepoem 
image = treepoem.generate_barcode(
    barcode_type='datamatrix',  # One of the supported codes.
    data='barcode payload', 
) 
image.convert('1').save('barcode.png')
```

We also need to install ghostscript to run this.

https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html

For any errors while running in windows please follow the below link.

[Treepoem barcode generator unable to find ghostscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828456/treepoem-barcode-generator-unable-to-find-ghostscript#answer-59548705)